# Some packages in mint not updating

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, upgrade, repository

I'm new to Linux Mint 12 and I can't tell for sure, but I think I'm missing some updates.  When I run update manager and it's fetching the list of packages to be updated, a bunch of packages list status: failed.

And when I run sudo apt-get update, a couple packages say Hit but most are listed as Ign (which I assume stands for Ignored).

I know that Mint purposely avoids installing some updates because they're not yet considered stable, but this looks like it's not even fetching the list of available updates.

Specifically I added the repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/jamesodhunt/bug-829980/ubuntu for a particular bug-fix which didn't seem to work, I think because the repository is being ignored.

I can't seem to find any references anywhere to other people having the same problem.  Everything I've found where people are having trouble fetching packages for updates, they seem to be getting explicit error messages, but I don't see any.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added ppa directly with apt-add-repository command then it might setup the ppa for maya ie(Mint). I would ask you to check that out in software sources. (Search for software sources app in mint menu). There under the tab 'Other software'. Select the ppa you have installed.Click edit and change the option under 'Distribution' from 'maya' to 'precise'. Then save it run run update manager again.

If the above said option fails: It would of better  if you could check which packages are being held back. If the package belongs to the ppa then nothing much can be done other than to disable that ppa.
For that I would recommend ppa-purge or y ppa manager.

Regarding your doubt of Ign and Hits while updating software database, it's quite normal. And most of the ignored ones are translation packages. So dont worry. Only thing which you should worry is if at the end of update process it throws out error saying some packages couldn't be updated.

Comment: It set up the ppa for oneiric.  I tried changing it to precise, but I just got 404: Not found

Comment: I ran sudo ppa-purge ppa:jamesodhunt/bug-829980 and now my problems are much much worse.
Whenever I run sudo apt-get update, I get
E: Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jamesodhunt-bug-829980-oneiric.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: I figured that out.  I removed it in software sources and I removed /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jamesodhunt-bug-829980-oneiric.list, but I still need some way to fix the bug

Comment: I'm not clear on what was the next thing you were suggesting that I do

Comment: If you deleted that the ppa file from your sources.list.d then you should be able to run update manager without problem.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake, The latest Linux mint is 13 and it is based on precise. So I had suggested to replace it precise. If it is setup for oneiric then it is right for your version of Mint.

Comment: In first paragraph I wanted you edit your ppa file make it link to ubuntu not mint itself. But as you said it is already setup for oneiric so no problem there.

Comment: Second paragraph was about disabling that ppa. Which can be done by just unticking that ppa in software sources or by ppa-purge. (Note: ppa-purge becomes usful if your ppa has replaced lots of files from standard repositories.) And by what you have said I think you have tried both those options.

Comment: Third paragraph was about your doubt regarding seeing a pakages as being marked as hit or Ign while updating the repositories.

Comment: But I still dont understand whether your problem is related to the ppa at all. It would be better if you could provide following data: 1) You didn't say wat packages are held back. 2) To which repo do they belong. 3) Do you have any other ppa installed.

Comment: 1) The only packages being held back are linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic

2) They are all in repo oneiric-updates/main

3) No other ppa installed

I have no other ppa installed as far as I know

Comment: Then please run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'. That should solve the problem.

Comment: But according to update manager, these are level 5, meaning "Dangerous packages.  Known to affect the stability of the systems depending on certain specs or hardware".  Shouldn't I wait til they're no longer marked level 5?

In any case, what would they even have to do with the ppa?

Comment: Despite my concerns, I ran dist-upgrade anyway.  I tried restarting and nothing was fixed.  I then went ahead and added the ppa again and still nothing was fixed